# What is this triangle wireless connection in Windows 8?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8

[image: What kind of connection is this?]

I just saw this connection show up in my wireless network list in Windows 8.

Comment: It resembles the older [Ad-Hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) [icon](http://cdn.blogsdna.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/Windows-7-Starter-Adhoc-Wifi.png), which is a network built over non-existing infrastructues..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the [ad-hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) wireless connections:

> A wireless ad hoc network is a decentralized type of wireless network.
>   The network is ad hoc because it does not rely on a preexisting
>   infrastructure, such as routers in wired networks or access points in
>   managed (infrastructure) wireless networks. Instead, each node
>   participates in routing by forwarding data for other nodes, and so the
>   determination of which nodes forward data is made dynamically based on
>   the network connectivity. In addition to the classic routing, ad hoc
>   networks can use flooding for forwarding the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah basically its an ad-hoc network. What that means is that you are directly connected to someones PC via wireless, as opposed to the ordinary method where you would both connect to a Wireless Access Point.